# Install sqsh for freetds (Sql Server)

Tags: linux, makefile, freetds, sqsh

**Duplicate: [I can't make SQSH 2.1.7 with freetds 0.91](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491222/i-cant-make-sqsh-2-1-7-with-freetds-0-91)**

I am trying to install sqsh for freetds (SQL Server) as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/150895/7507).  I installed freetds under `/opt/freetds`.

However, I am getting the following error building sqsh:

```
[noahlz:sqsh-2.4]$ sudo ./configure --prefix=/opt/sqsh 

...

configure: error: Unable to locate Sybase installation. Check your SYBASE environment variable setting.
```

I tried setting `export SYBASE=/opt/freetds` to no avail.

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491222/i-cant-make-sqsh-2-1-7-with-freetds-0-91

Thanks & Regards,  
Alok

Answer (score 3):

On OS X I'd suggest:

```
brew install sqsh
```

Man, [I love Hombrew](http://brew.sh).

Comment: It's been migrated to the "boneyard" unfortunately. https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/dc07dcfaa89f0ee30d8eddf3ed5cce320c4e9953#Formula/sqsh.rb You can still brew it from there though. https://superuser.com/questions/1110414/install-a-deleted-homebrew-formulae

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the sudo command to configure the build environment. Just run

```
export SYBASE=/opt/freetds
./configure --prefix=/opt/sqsh
```

I would recommend to add --with-readline as well. Then run

```
make
sudo make install
```

So you only need sudo when you want to install the product and need root authorizations to do that. Please note that a newer version sqsh-2.4 is available for download from Sourceforge.

HTH, Martin.